# spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf and thymeleaf-layout-dialect works without explicit LayoutDialect bean - is it OK?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot Maven project:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

In dependencies there are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The versions are:

- `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:3.2.0`
- `nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar:3.3.0`

[This instruction](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html) says:

> To get started with Layout Dialect we need to include it into the pom.xml. The dependency is:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
>   <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
>   <version>2.0.5</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> We will also need to configure the integration by adding an additional dialect to our template engine:
>
> ```
> @Bean
> public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
>     SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
>     ...
>     templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
>     return templateEngine;
> }
> ```

I don't add the `SpringTemplateEngine` bean and my project works.

Some other instructions say I need to add the `nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.LayoutDialect` bean that I also don't add.

For investigation purpose I use the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @Autowired
    LayoutDialect layoutDialect;

    @GetMapping("/demo")
    public String getAllUsers() {
        System.out.println(layoutDialect);
        return "thymeleaf_first_page";
    }
}
```

And in the console i see:

```
nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.layoutdialect.LayoutDialect@7c6ab057
```

That means that the bean exists in the context.

**QUESTION**

Can you confirm that with my newer versions of Spring Boot and `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` it's not required to explicitly add the `LayoutDialect` bean?

Is there any documentation about it?

**UPDATE**

This is not much important for the question but will add some illustration of what was done.

The layout is (`src/main/resources/templates/layout/layout.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title layout:fragment="title"></title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav><span>LOGO</span> <a href="#">LINK1</a> <a href="#">LINK2</a> </nav>
</header>
    <main id="mainpart" layout:fragment="main">
        <p><em>This content must not be visible.</em></p>
    </main>
<footer>Footer information</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is (`src/main/resources/templates/thymeleaf_first_page.html`):

```
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/layout}">
<head>
    <title layout:fragment="title">Thymeleaf demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main layout:fragment="main">
        <h1>Thymeleaf template extension demo</h1>
        <p>Actual page content: [<th:block th:text="${modelValue}" />]</p>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <title>Thymeleaf demo</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav><span>LOGO</span> <a href="#">LINK1</a> <a href="#">LINK2</a> </nav>
</header>
    <main id="mainpart">
        <h1>Thymeleaf template extension demo</h1>
        <p>Actual page content: [some value from the model]</p>
    </main>
<footer>Footer information</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like as for the Thymeleaf version 3.1 template extension is supposed to be done using the other mechanism described in [Tutorial: Using Thymeleaf (3.1.2.RELEASE), chapter 8.5 Layout Inheritance](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#layout-inheritance):

The layout is (`src/main/resources/templates/layout/layout_simple.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" th:fragment="layout(title, main)"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title th:replace="${title}">Layout title</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Common block: header</header>
<main id="mainpart" th:replace="${main}">
    <p><em>This content must not be visible.</em></p>
</main>
<footer>Common block: footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The page is (`src/main/resources/templates/thymeleaf_first_page_simple.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html th:replace="~{layout/layout_simple :: layout(~{::title}, ~{::main})}"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Thymeleaf demo simple</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <h1>Thymeleaf template extension simple demo</h1>
    <p>Actual page content: [<th:block th:text="${modelValue}" />]</p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Thymeleaf demo simple</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>Common block: header</header>
<main>
    <h1>Thymeleaf template extension simple demo</h1>
    <p>Actual page content: [some simple value from the model]</p>
</main>
<footer>Common block: footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

So no need to use the dependency `nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:jar` (and to define the `LayoutDialect` bean).